# Match slash in bbe

Tags: sed

How can I match a forward slash in `bbe`?

If I have this text file called `test.txt`:

```
foo / bar
```

I can match it in `sed` like so:

```
sed -e 's/foo \/ bar/it worked!/' test.txt
```

However when doing the same thing in `bbe` it doesn't replace it:

```
bbe -e 's/foo \/ bar/it worked!/' test.txt
```

I have also tried double escaping and triple escaping the slash, however it doesn't seem to work anyway.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how to escape the `/`, but some alternate solutions:

- Using a hex escape sequence: `'s/foo \x2F bar/it worked!/'`
- Using a different delimiter such as underscore: `'s_foo / bar_it worked!_'`